# Building a library that consumes a WEBAPI Restful service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have created a WebApi Project that serves data to other systems.

At the moment, each system that consumes the API have all the API urls hardcoded and there is a lot of duplicated logic to call and convert data from the API in each system. I am new to webAPI and am struggling to find examples of how I can wrap the calling logic, data conversion and urls into a library that all the systems can share. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You might want to check out my book chapter on building a client here http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch09.html  It is still in pre-release so feedback is welcomed.

Comment: Thanks Darrel, I will have a read.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a client library.

You can build all that boiler plate code in a Class Library project inside the API solution and call it YourApiClient and then just distribute the compiled DLL to all your clients.

The only thing to keep in mind and manage is the distribution process whenever you make changes to the API or to the client library.

Comment: No 5#1+ sherlock. totally unhelpful